# Bipartite graph degree property proof/disproof

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be the set of all bipartite graphs.

Prove/disprove that there exists some bipartite graph that satisfies the following property:

> - minDeg+maxDeg>|V|
>
>   where minDeg is the minimal degree out of all vertices in the graph;
>     maxDeg the maximum degree out of all vertices in the graph and |V| is the total number of vertices in the graph.

I'd say that this property is true for bipartite graphs, because I can simply have  this graph:

A=B ..... (- is a single edge, = are two parallel edges connecting vertices A,B)

Thus, minDeg=2, maxDeg=2.... 4>2

But this kind of relies on the "fact" that bipartite graphs can be multigraphs (and I'm not too sure if they can). I've gone through the definition and haven't found any indications that would unambigiously state that a bipartite graph CANNOT be a multigraph (have parallel edges).

Am I wrong here? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Say $G=(A,B)$ is a bipartite graph. Then $|V|=|A|+|B|$, and notice that $\operatorname{maxDeg}\leq \max\{|A|,|B|\}$ and $\operatorname{minDeg}\leq \min\{|A|,|B|\}$. So, $\operatorname{maxDeg}+\operatorname{maxDeg}\leq |A|+|B|=|V|$,  thus a graph like the one you described cannot exists. Am I doing something wrong? The only possibility that I see for $G$ is that there are multiedges, and the $\operatorname{degree}(v)$s count the number of edges from $v$ instead of the number of points $v$ conects with.

Comment: @Wore Thanks for the quick answer! Wouldn't |V|=|A|+|B| apply only if we were to assume that no bipartite graph is a multigraph? By definition, vertices from set1 should only be connected to vertices from set2 (applies for set2-set1 as well...) - but having 2 edges connect the same 2 vertices from different sets should still count as a bipartite graph. Or not?